# how to get all attributes of products in magento 2?

Tags: magento2

Is there any way to get all attributes of configurable products in the product listing page. Like as magento 1

```
<?php $simple_collection = $conf->getUsedProductCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addFilterByRequiredOptions(); ?>
```

So how to show all attributes ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We should try:

```
    /**
     * @var \Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\Type\Con‌​figurable
     */
    protected $configurableType;
    .......

   $collection = $this->configurableType->getUsedProductCollection($this->getProduct())
                           ->add‌​AttributeToSelect('*‌​')
                           ->addFilterByRequi‌​redOptions();
```

Comment: if we don't want any change in the core files, is there any way to call all of that attributes inside our list.phtml file in the theme?

Comment: We should override the core Magento. Actually, we can get the collection directly on phtml by using object Manager. But, this way discourages by Magento 2 best practice.

Comment: exactly i am overriding the core magento code. can you please share the code using object manager code, how to get all attributes?

Comment: thanks khoa...but using this code we just get 'name' only. I want all the attributes and show all of them with corresponding values in an array? can we get all attributes in an array? so that using loop we can display all the attributes and their values?

Comment: You should try `$product = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance() ->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory'); $product->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*');`

Comment: sorry dude...but its not working....:(

Comment: `<?php$conf = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')->setProduct($firstProduct);
  //echo($conf);
  $simple_collection = $conf->getUsedProductCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addFilterByRequiredOptions(); ?>` this code was using in magento 1...and i want it for magento 2....

Comment: You can try `$productConfig = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()
            ->create('Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\Type\Configurable');

        $simple_collection = $productConfig->getUsedProductCollection($firstProduct)->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addFilterByRequiredOptions();`

Comment: If my answer is helpful for you, please accept it.